# Cannot resolve symbol HttpUrl Android Studio

Tags: java, android, http

I am working on an app that saves web pages offline. Android Studio could not resolve symbol HttpUrl. Please tell me is there a library I need to add for it to recognize it. Example of the code is:

```
HttpUrl url = HttpUrl.parse("http://" + HttpUrl.parse(document.baseUri()).host() + path);
            iconUrls.add(url.toString())
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
    HttpURLConnection(URL url);

And for reference go to:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html

Comment: Thanks. Can you restructure the format of how the code will be if I am to use HttpURLConnection. Thanks'

Comment: Assign your web address in the url.

Answer (score 0):

The [class](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) you need is `HttpURLConnection`, that's why it's complaining.

I've used for my personal needs this library, [OkHttp,](http://square.github.io/okhttp/) and I found it great and easy to use. You might try **OkHttp** out.